# How does adding an unused generic parameter to an interface stop a class implementing it?

Tags: java, generics, interface

The following code

```
public interface IGiveUp
{
    void surrender(List<Class> l);
}
public class GiveUp implements IGiveUp {

    @Override public void surrender(List<Class> l) {}
}
```

compiles fine. But when I add an unused generic type parameter to the interface

```
public interface IGiveUp<X>
{
    void surrender(List<Class> l);
}
```

it fails to compile (javac 1.6.0_23)

```
IGiveUp.GiveUp is not abstract and does not override abstract method surrender(java.util.List)
```

It will compile if I either specify the generic in the implementation

```
public class GiveUp implements IGiveUp<Object>
```

or make the method parameter a list of not a generic type

```
void surrender(List l);
```

Comment: @RohitJain I think the question is "**why?**" :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your class is trying to implement the [*raw* type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) `IGiveUp` - that raw type doesn't know anything about generics, so the method signature after [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) is then just:

```
void surrender(List l)
```

It doesn't matter that the method parameter didn't use a type parameter from the interface declaration: type erasure removes *all traces* of generics from signatures.

Basically, you should avoid raw types as far as possible. For more details, follow the links above to sections of the JLS, or read the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Comment: Ah, so basically they couldn't be bothered to get partial erasure working, so punted it to be my problem! Ironically I was adding a type parameter to improve things, only to find that migrating implementing classes one by one is not an option. Thanks

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor: The point is that raw types really only existed as a way of getting backward compatibility. They weren't intended to be used in this way. You could always create a generic interface which is either a superinterface or a subinterface of the non-generic one, and migrate classes one by one that way.